# How do i retrieve Eth from a contact that i created?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, assembly

New to blockchain.. havent a clue.. I managed to create a new contract with Eth. I moved money from MyEtherum Wallet to Metamask and into a contract, somehow? I have no coding experience but need someone to help with getting my Eth back out of the contract.. From looking around myetherwallet i found a ABI/JSON interface and now wondering if this is where the withdrawal code goes. If so anyone any idea what it might be? I created the contract on mainnet.

Is this the correct way to withdraw Eth from a contract to a wallet?

Im new at this.. have no clue.

Using 'MyEtherwallet' and 'Metamask' Also have the address of the contract.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This contract seems to have no methods :
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf6ab4331fb8dde0bb10f58bd0cc818514736a74f#code

I'm afraid that your ETH will be stuck there forever.

Comment: Is there no way to amend the contract as i created it? I have no idea about programming.

Comment: No, sorry... once a contract is "published" _on-chain_, there is absolutely no way you can modify it. It's one of the properties of a blockchain : immutability.

Answer (score 0):

Contracts behave differently than ethereum addresses, they don't include private keys so you cannot sign transactions the typical way. Your eth are stuck forever unless your contract have built in eth `transfer` method or `selfdestruct` method.

Comment: My contract has 10Eth in it.. would like to get it out again.No idea how i did it. How can i find out if it has these methods built in? transfer?

Comment: Show us the the address of the contract or the code. Also how did you manage to create contract without knowing what methods your contract contains??

Comment: 0xf6aB4331FB8Dde0bb10F58BD0cc818514736a74f  I tried to put the Eth into Etherum Gold contract and something went wrong..

Comment: If you help me get it back i will send you some Eth as payment for your help.

Comment: @Soupdragon: You've created [a contract with no code](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e8fc87b8b5f3dcfde1ba9854c71c365506976ff48ed6e472d03ec9011afe85e). Why???